# How to create a variable in C# to hold date?

Tags: c#, datetime, variables, datetime-format

Can someone give me the code that has 2 variables. 1 variable holds the date & the other displays in longdate format.

Comment: What date/longdate are you talking about?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx)?

Comment: A date variable is a date variable.  It's up to you, during the formatting output process, to print it out as a long date.

Comment: A little research by yourself might have proven less degrading ey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; // will give the date for today
string dateWithFormat = date.ToLongDateString();
```

You can further modify how the format of the string. You can do this by `date.ToString("dd - MM - yyyy");` which would output something like `09 - 15 - 2011`

You can [read about this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

string longDateString = myDate.ToLongDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

string longDate = date.ToLongDateString();
```

Comment: DateTime.Now is a property and not a method. So "DateTime.Now()" is wrong and should be "DateTime.Now".